# Изменение части данных в pandas.DataFrame по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, edit

Нужно дополнить отсутствующие данные одной колонки `kks_amount` `DF`, значениями из другой `amount 1 bl`, по условиям. 
Решил это так:

```
python
df_equip['kks_amount'].loc[(df_equip['kks_amount'].isnull()) &
                              (df_equip['block'] == 1) & 
                             (df_equip['amount 1 bl'] == 1) &   
                             (df_equip['kks_piese'].isin(['Да'])) &
                             (df_equip['mcs'].isin(['Нет']))] = 
                    df_equip['amount 1 bl']
```

В результате вывелось сообщение:

```
C:\Users\Zhuravlev\Python\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py:190: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
```

Посмотрел по ссылке, но толком не понял, что нужно в данной ситуации сделать.
Понимаю, что надо выравнять индексы. 
Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно поступать с такой задачей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не совсем правильно используете `.loc[]`. Попробуйте так:

```
mask = (df_equip['kks_amount'].isnull()) &
                              (df_equip['block'] == 1) & 
                             (df_equip['amount 1 bl'] == 1) &   
                             (df_equip['kks_piese'].isin(['Да'])) &
                             (df_equip['mcs'].isin(['Нет']))
df_equip.loc[mask, 'kks_amount'] = df_equip['amount 1 bl']
```

Comment: Спасибо @MaxU. Все срослось без проблем!!!

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, почему после исполнения кода (`kks_amount` заполнен данными) используя маску для проверки df_equip.loc[mask, current_columns], я получаю тот же слайс, без учета условия в маске df_equip['kks_amount'].isnull())? Ожидается, что выборка должна быть пустой...

Comment: @БорисЖуравлев, для того чтобы ответить на этот вопрос мне понадобится небольшой __воспроизводимый__ пример входных и выходных данных. Лучше открыть новый вопрос с примером данных. Специально для таких случаев я написал [небольшой туториал](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)